# Como puedo fusionar dos columnas de dos filas diferentes en Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Me gustaría lograr algo así:

[image: Resultado deseado]

Pero lo máximo que he logrado es lo siguiente:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="col-6">
        <span class="pr-4">
            <i class="fa fal fa-eye" style="font-size:16px"></i>
            <span class="card-text">3</span>
        </span>
        <span>
            <i class="fa fal fa-comment-alt" style="font-size:16px"></i>
            <span class="card-text">3</span>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="clearfix" style="margin-right: 1em;">
            <a href="/news/article/1" class="readMore">Read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row d-flex align-items-left">
    <div class="col-6">
        Published
    </div>
</div>
```

**¿cómo puedo fusionar la columna 2 de la fila 1 con la columna 2 de la fila 2?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas se cono ce como **Nested rows** o filas anidadas y son parte del sistema de grilla o **Grid system**. [Aquí la documentación oficial](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#nesting).

Se trata de generar varias filas dentro de una fila y ordenar los elementos según tu necesidad.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.5/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
          <i class="bi bi-eye"></i>
          <span class="card-text">3</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <i class="bi bi-chat"></i>
          <span class="card-text">3</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span class="card-text">Published</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="clearfix" style="margin-right: 1em;">
        <a href="/news/article/1" class="readMore">Read more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Cambié los íconos de **FontAwesome** por los que vienen incluidos en **Bootstrap Icons** y cambié los `span` que usas para los contadores por `div` ya que los `span` por defecto no son elementos `inline`, lo que genera un "salto de línea" entre ellos, pero puedes retomar lo que tienes y probar con ello.

Comment: Me ganaron la respuesta jeje. Pero aunque no viene al caso, también se pueden usar  las clásicas tablas sin llegar a comprometer el diseño.

Comment: Gracias a ambos.